# Google Search Console - Internal error encountered

Tags: google-search-api, google-apis-explorer

Recently when calling the api for Google Search Console, I'm getting:

> "Internal error encountered"

Everything is working well last week but until now still getting the issue. Is there any problem with  Google Search Console?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Even your search api tool in [google.developer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/searchconsole/v1/searchconsole.urlTestingTools.mobileFriendlyTest.run) page is not working. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg9vV.png)